# How to display items in a table view controller from 2 arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to IOS development. I am stuck at a place where I want to display something in a table view controller. In the first row I have this name called "All Fences" and for the rest of the rows below that, I have an array which contains all the other names.

Here's what I am doing:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:@"All Fences"];
[self fetchOtherArray];
}
-(void) fetchOtherArray{
// I have array2 here
}
```

Can you tell me how to get everything displayed .

Thanks

Comment: Do you want something like a sectioned tableview ? Can you give some images please?

Comment: It seems like you need to add sections in table view, you should learn from some tutorial how to add sections in table view, it is just the same as plain writing on paper, you write HEADING then you write some bullets in it, then you write other HEADINGS, and other bullets, so sections and rows works same in table view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that array has one string and that you have defined array2 in your header file, do this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{        
     return  [array2 count]+1;
}
```

Use this checking inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if(indexPath.row=0){
 // set name "All Fences"
  cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else{
  // set from another array
   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you merge your array2 into array1? or take some temporary array & merge arra1 & arra2 in that so that it'll be easier for you to fetch the value from single array & you can perform an action in didselectrowatindexpath on a single array.

Take a look at this so that you can have idea.

```
NSMutableArray *arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr1 addObject:@"first"];                             // your first array
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arr2 addObject:@"second"];                            // your second array

 [arr1 addObject:[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]];
 NSLog(@"arr1 >> %@",arr1);

// mediator array
NSMutableArray *arr_temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[arr1 objectAtIndex:0],[arr2 objectAtIndex:0] ,nil];
NSLog(@"arr_temp >>%@",arr_temp);
```

I'm insisting you to store both array values in temporary array . Like the second way you can see in code, if you don't want to modify your array1 in order to reuse later.